# Сбрасывает alias после перезагрузки

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

После перезагрузки терминала - слетают добавленные мной alias команды. Как правильно задавать команда alias, чтобы они оставались в системе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавьте их в «ресурсный» файл вашей оболочки. имя оболочки можно узнать, например, так:

```
$ echo $SHELL
```

например, ответом будет:

```
/bin/bash
```

значит, оболочка — `bash`, а «ресурсный» файл — `~/.bashrc`

а если ответом будет, к примеру, `/bin/zsh`, то оболочка — `zsh`, а файл — `~/.zshrc`

этот файл интерпретируется оболочкой при каждом её запуске.